# Create a unique number with javascript time

Tags: javascript, time, numbers, unique

I need to generate unique id numbers on the fly using javascript. In the past, I've done this by creating a number using time.  The number would be made up of the four digit year, two digit month, two digit day, two digit hour, two digit minute, two digit second, and three digit millisecond. So it would look something like this: 20111104103912732  ... this would give enough certainty of a unique number for my purposes.

It's been a while since I've done this and I don't have the code anymore. Anyone have the code to do this, or have a better suggestion for generating a unique ID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a GUID / UUID in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you considered `new Date().toISOString ()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you just want a unique-ish number, then

```
var timestamp = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
```

would get you a simple number. But if you need the readable version, you're in for a bit of processing:

```
var now = new Date();

timestamp = now.getFullYear().toString(); // 2011
timestamp += (now.getMonth < 9 ? '0' : '') + now.getMonth().toString(); // JS months are 0-based, so +1 and pad with 0's
timestamp += ((now.getDate < 10) ? '0' : '') + now.getDate().toString(); // pad with a 0
... etc... with .getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds(), getMilliseconds()
```

Comment: @Áxel: I didn't say it's unique, I said it's "unique-ish". of course using a timestamp generated client-side is going to generate dupes.

Comment: timestamp should be `new Date().getTime();` the `date.getUTCMilliseconds()` returns a number between 0 and 999. `date.getTime()` returns milliseconds since 1st Jan. 1970. (normal timestamp). http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: -1, since the question was about *unique* number. First block of code should be omitted entirely.

Comment: This can generate 2 unique values: `function foo1() {console.log(new Date().getUTCMilliseconds()); console.log(new Date().getUTCMilliseconds()); }`

Comment: getUTCMilliseconds `The value returned by getUTCMilliseconds() is an integer between 0 and 999.`. This is the worst idea for unique id, first paragraph should be removed.

Comment: return same number, because the process occurs on same time :)

Comment: the answer below is better because it has better chances of providing uniqueness. e.g. if you are looping through a list and assigning objects an ID, this method above will create dupes

Comment: I think it is a very good first approach in simple scenarios. thanks

Comment: Simple `Date.now()` can be used if timestamp suffies the need. But inside any fast loop this will not give unique values. like: `[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(item => console.log(Date.now()))`

Comment: `(Math.random().toString().replace('.',Math.random().toString().replace('.','')))` this will give unique number even inside fast loop

Comment: Will this create unique id `Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)`?

Answer (score 145):

A better approach would be:

```
new Date().valueOf();
```

instead of

```
new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
```

**valueOf()** is "most likely" a unique number.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp.

Comment: It is not a unique number.. milliseconds is not granular enough to be considered unique.

Comment: Or simply `+new Date()`

Comment: I just ran a for loop and I got duplicate results with `valueOf()`.
I just use this - `+performance.now().toString().replace('.', 7)`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: @ItzikBenHutta Got 3 times the same value.  Using multi-core CPU, probably a race condition with threads.

Answer (score 142):

The shortest way to create a number that you can be pretty sure will be unique among as many separate instances as you can think of is

```
Date.now() + Math.random()
```

If there is a 1 millisecond difference in function call, it is **100% guaranteed to generate a different number**. For function calls within the same millisecond you should only start to be worried if you are creating more than a few million numbers within this same millisecond, which is not very probable.

For more on the probability of getting a repeated number within the same millisecond see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220928/4617597

Comment: Also, if you want to keep all the bits of the random number you can generate them separately and merge as strings:

    new Date().valueOf().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2) That will give you a 19 character alphanumeric string which is a decent amount of entropy. Albeit half of it is predictable.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as when trying other higher voted answers, I got 2 and even 3 times the same value in a row when calling from an async function.  This seems to provide enough randomness for a standard 8-core CPU to generate 8 unique strings exactly at the same moment, good enough for my use.

Comment: Best one: ```Date.now() + '' + Math.random()```

Comment: `Date.now()` portion will be useless when this will be inside a simple/fast loop

Comment: IMHO, the best solution is to use `Math.floor(Date.now() * Math.random())`. You will do have duplicates if you use only Date.now() in a loop, but Math.random() makes it unique.

Comment: I checked on a 1 million item loop and it passed. Pretty unique for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-unique-id

Comment: Or you can use `Math.floor(Date.now() * Math.random() / 1000)` if you need to fit into int32 (int in SQL)

Comment: @APu even if it's locked on the same timestamps while generating bunch of random sub numbers, it will be very limited, and the randomness will just reset on the next timestamp. However, if you find yourself challenged with such of speed, I suppose this Company will also have its own cryptographic team to solve that.

Comment: This approach is used by Universally Unique Lexicographically Sortable Identifiers (ulid) https://github.com/ulid/spec

Answer (score 25):

Here's what I do when I want something smaller than a bunch of numbers - change base.

```
var uid = (new Date().getTime()).toString(36)
```

Comment: @blushrt true, it can cause rare clashes. You could md5 the timestamp using something like https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/, but for my purposes it was "unique enough", and more importantly, faster.

Comment: @frumbert, it depends. MD5 isn't collision resistant either. But in your case I got into trouble very fast because of toString(36) which I assume converts numerical value to it's ascii representation, not sure though, but i can see the problem, if you call your uuid generator often enough, only last 3 chars are changing so the chances are high that you will get into a collision. You get much better odds if you just stick to new Date.getTime() calls. But hey if it worked for your purposes, no problem, i needed it for some unique ids only  for my client side code, ended up using uuid node lib.

Comment: I love this one! I've adjusted it to `(Date.now() + Math.random()).toString(36)` to prevent millisecond clashes. It's short and generates something like "k92g5pux.i36"

Answer (score 17):

This performs faster than creating a `Date` instance, uses less code and will *always* produce a unique number (locally):

```
function uniqueNumber() {
    var date = Date.now();

    // If created at same millisecond as previous
    if (date <= uniqueNumber.previous) {
        date = ++uniqueNumber.previous;
    } else {
        uniqueNumber.previous = date;
    }

    return date;
}

uniqueNumber.previous = 0;
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8aLocan/

I've released this on Bower and npm: https://github.com/stevenvachon/unique-number

You could also use something more elaborate such as [cuid](https://github.com/ericelliott/cuid), [puid](https://github.com/pid/puid) or [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid) to generate a non-number.

Comment: It seems to me that adding the random numbers would actually make it LESS full proof.  With just the time stamp, two numbers would have to be created at the exact same millisecond to be the same.  By adding two random numbers, you've now created many combinations of numbers, due to math, that could end up with the same result when multiplied.  I know it's unlikely, but ... isn't that right?

Comment: Hmm, yes. Perhaps a combination of My answer and abarber's answer would be best.

Comment: Good effort, not trying to pick on your answer... but this new solution doesn't actually solve the "more than one id created at the same millisecond" issue because, ya know .. it's javascript, on the CLIENT side.  If a different user created a number at the same exact millisecond , it wouldn't be reflected in uniqueNumber.previous of the 'other' user.  Unless you store it on the server somewhere and check for uniqueness... there's just no way that a purely js-based solution like this can be _certain_ it is creating a unique number.

Comment: Well, that would be a more elaborate system than just a unique number.

Comment: I like this as a simple locally unique id generator.  Quick and easy.  I've combined it with @frumbert's solution of base36ing it.

Answer (score 17):

I use

```
Math.floor(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random())
```

So if by any chance the code is fired at the same time there is also a teeny chance that the random numbers will be the same.

Comment: Not sure `new Date()` is useful tough. You could get the same numbers with two different dates

Comment: I mean, how is it better than simply doing `Math.random()`?

Answer (score 16):

In 2024, you can use the in-browser [Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) to generate cryptographically strong random values.

```js
function getRandomNumbers() {
  const typedArray = new Uint8Array(10);
  const randomValues = window.crypto.getRandomValues(typedArray);
  return randomValues.join('');
}

console.log(getRandomNumbers());
// 1857488137147725264738
```

```js
function getRandomNumbers() {
  const typedArray = new Uint8Array(10);
  const randomValues = window.crypto.getRandomValues(typedArray);
  return randomValues.join('');
}

console.log(getRandomNumbers());
```

both [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) constructor and [Crypto.getRandomValues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) are supported on all major browsers, including IE11

Comment: only work with ssl connection, so it can cause issues with local http connection

Answer (score 10):

This should do :

```
var uniqueNumber = new Date().getTime(); // milliseconds since 1st Jan. 1970
```

Comment: Useful for many cases, eventough this does not really generate pure "unique" ids, in case this function is called multiple times in the same millisecond... But anyway, for user and UI interaction, that's good.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Lots of irrelevant crap which is difficult and unnecessary, and this answer gives unique time per each millisecond.

Answer (score 9):

if you want a unique number after few mili seconds then use `Date.now()`, if you want to use it inside a `for loop` then use `Date.now() and Math.random()` together

**unique number inside a for loop**

```
function getUniqueID(){
    for(var i = 0; i< 5; i++)
      console.log(Date.now() + ( (Math.random()*100000).toFixed()))
}
getUniqueID()
```

**output:: all numbers are unique**

`15598251485988384
155982514859810330
155982514859860737
155982514859882244
155982514859883316`

**unique number without `Math.random()`**

```
function getUniqueID(){
        for(var i = 0; i< 5; i++)
          console.log(Date.now())
    }
    getUniqueID()
```

**output:: Numbers are repeated**

`1559825328327
1559825328327
1559825328327
1559825328328
1559825328328`

Answer (score 5):

From investigating online I came up with the following object that creates a unique id per session:

```
        window.mwUnique ={
        prevTimeId : 0,
        prevUniqueId : 0,
        getUniqueID : function(){
            try {
                var d=new Date();
                var newUniqueId = d.getTime();
                if (newUniqueId == mwUnique.prevTimeId)
                    mwUnique.prevUniqueId = mwUnique.prevUniqueId + 1;
                else {
                    mwUnique.prevTimeId = newUniqueId;
                    mwUnique.prevUniqueId = 0;
                }
                newUniqueId = newUniqueId + '' + mwUnique.prevUniqueId;
                return newUniqueId;                     
            }
            catch(e) {
                mwTool.logError('mwUnique.getUniqueID error:' + e.message + '.');
            }
        }            
    }
```

It maybe helpful to some people.

Cheers

Andrew

Comment: this is the simplest and error proof solution to date about this question. I have tried a different solution (see below), but I have still some concerns about it that need further development.

Answer (score 4):

This also should do:

```
(function() {
    var uniquePrevious = 0;
    uniqueId = function() {
        return uniquePrevious++;
    };
}());
```

Comment: Very similar implementation you can find in lodash UniqueId function, for me, your solution is simple and clean.

Answer (score 4):

In ES6:

```
const ID_LENGTH = 36
const START_LETTERS_ASCII = 97 // Use 64 for uppercase
const ALPHABET_LENGTH = 26

const uniqueID = () => [...new Array(ID_LENGTH)]
  .map(() => String.fromCharCode(START_LETTERS_ASCII + Math.random() * ALPHABET_LENGTH))
 .join('')
```

Example:

```
 > uniqueID()
 > "bxppcnanpuxzpyewttifptbklkurvvetigra"
```

Comment: if unique ID is what you want just do `btoa(Date()) `

Answer (score 4):

> Always get unique Id in JS

```
function getUniqueId(){
   return (new Date().getTime()).toString(36) + new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
}

getUniqueId()    // Call the function

------------results like

//"ka2high4264"

//"ka2hj115905"

//"ka2hj1my690"

//"ka2hj23j287"

//"ka2hj2jp869"
```

Comment: This will not give truly unique value, try this code with this `[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(item => getUniqueId());`

Answer (score 3):

Updated for 2021, numbers and ids are not guaranteed to be unique but should be satisfactory unique enough:

(oh, and who knew `something.toString(36)` is even a thing )

```js
// a pseudo-random floating number based on Date.now()
const generateRandomNumber = () =>
  Math.log2(Date.now()) + Math.random();

console.log("a pseudo-random floating number based on Date.now():");
console.log(generateRandomNumber());

// a locally unique-ish HTML id
const generateUniqueId = () => `_${Date.now().toString(36)}${Math.floor(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER * Math.random()).toString(36)}`;

console.log("a locally unique-ish HTML id:");
console.log(generateUniqueId())

// a pseudo-random BigInt
const generateRandomBigInt = () =>
  BigInt(Date.now()) * BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) +
  BigInt(Math.floor(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER * Math.random()));

console.log("a pseudo-random BigInt:");
console.log(generateRandomBigInt().toString());

// same but base32-encoded (each char is 5 bits)

console.log("same but base32-encoded (each char is 5 bits):");
console.log(generateRandomBigInt().toString(32));

// extracting the "Date.now" timestamp of when it was generated:

console.log('extracting the "Date.now" timestamp of when it was generated:');
console.log(Number(generateRandomBigInt() / BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)))

// generate a run of random BigInt in ascending order

function generateRandomBigIntFactory() {
  let count = 0, prev = 0;
  return () => {
    const now = Date.now();
    if (now === prev) { ++count; }
    else { count = 0; prev = now; }
    return (BigInt(now) * BigInt(16384) + BigInt(count)) * BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) +
      BigInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)); 
  }    
}

// verify the order is ascending
const generate = generateRandomBigIntFactory();
let prev = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
  const num = generate();
  if (num <= prev) console.log(`error: ${prev}, ${num}`);
  prev = num;
}

console.log("the last random BigInt:");
console.log(prev.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

use this:for creating unique number in javascript

```
var uniqueNumber=(new Date().getTime()).toString(36);
```

It really works.     :)

Comment: nice and simple.

Answer (score 2):

simple solution I found

var today = new Date().valueOf();

console.log( today );

Answer (score 1):

This creates an almost guaranteed unique 32 character key client side, if you want just numbers change the "chars" var.

```
var d = new Date().valueOf();
var n = d.toString();
var result = '';
var length = 32;
var p = 0;
var chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

for (var i = length; i > 0; --i){
    result += ((i & 1) && n.charAt(p) ? '<b>' + n.charAt(p) + '</b>' : chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)]);
    if(i & 1) p++;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j0evrdf1/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
    function UniqueValue(d){
        var dat_e = new Date();
        var uniqu_e = ((Math.random() *1000) +"").slice(-4)

        dat_e = dat_e.toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").replace(dat_e.getFullYear(),uniqu_e);
        if(d==dat_e)
            dat_e = UniqueValue(dat_e);
        return dat_e;
    }
```

Call 1: UniqueValue('0') 
Call 2: UniqueValue(UniqueValue('0')) // will be complex

Sample Output: 
for(var i =0;i<10;i++){ console.log(UniqueValue(UniqueValue('0')));} 
60950116113248802 
26780116113248803 
53920116113248803 
35840116113248803 
47430116113248803 
41680116113248803 
42980116113248804 
34750116113248804 
20950116113248804 
03730116113248804

Answer (score 1):

Since milliseconds are not updated every millisecond in node, following is an answer. This generates a unique human readable ticket number. I am new to programming and nodejs. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
function get2Digit(value) {
if (value.length == 1) return "0" + "" + value;
else return value;
```

}

```
function get3Digit(value) {
if (value.length == 1) return "00" + "" + value;
else return value;
```

}

```
function generateID() {
    var d = new Date();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = get2Digit(d.getMonth() + 1);
    var date = get2Digit(d.getDate());
    var hours = get2Digit(d.getHours());
    var minutes = get2Digit(d.getMinutes());
    var seconds = get2Digit(d.getSeconds());
    var millSeconds = get2Digit(d.getMilliseconds());
    var dateValue = year + "" + month + "" + date;
    var uniqueID = hours + "" + minutes + "" + seconds + "" + millSeconds;

    if (lastUniqueID == "false" || lastUniqueID < uniqueID) lastUniqueID = uniqueID;
    else lastUniqueID = Number(lastUniqueID) + 1;
    return dateValue + "" + lastUniqueID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let uuid = ((new Date().getTime()).toString(36))+'_'+(Date.now() + Math.random().toString()).split('.').join("_")
```

> sample result "k3jobnvt_15750033412250_18299601769317408"

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while trying to find a simple UID generation technique that was also sortable (so I can order by uid and items will appear in order of creation / uid generation). The major problem with most (all?) of the solutions here is that they either rely on millisecond accuracy (at best) == clashes(!) or a pseudo-random number == clashes(!) && non-sortable(!).

Technique below uses micro-second precision where available (i.e. not where fingerprinting-resistance techniques are in play, e.g. firefox) combined with an incrementing, stateful suffix. Not perfect, or particularly performant for large numbers of IDs (see example with 1,000,000 below), but it works and is reversible.

```js
// return a uid, sortable by creation order
let increment;
let tuidPrev;

const uid = (uidPrev) => {
  // get current time to microsecond precision (if available) and remove decimals
  const tuid = ((performance.timing.navigationStart + performance.now()) * 1000)
    // convert timestamp to base36 string
    .toString(36);

  // previous uid has been provided (stateful)
  if (uidPrev) {
    tuidPrev = uidPrev.slice(0, 10);
    increment = uidPrev.length > 10 ? parseInt(uidPrev.slice(10), 36) : 0;
  }

  // if tuid is changed reset the increment
  if (tuid !== tuidPrev) {
    tuidPrev = tuid;
    increment = 0;
  }

  // return timed uid + suffix (4^36 values) === very unique id!
  return tuid + ('000' + (increment++).toString(36)).slice(-4);
}


// EXAMPLE (check the console!)
const iterations = 1000000;
const uids = [];
const uidMap = {};
const timeMap = {}
const microMap = {};
let time = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  const id = uid();
  uids.push(id);
  uidMap[id] = i;
  timeMap[Date.now()] = i;
  microMap[performance.now()] = i;
}

console.log(`Time taken: ${performance.now() - time}ms`);
console.log('Unique IDs:', Object.keys(uidMap).length.toLocaleString());
console.log('Clashing timestamps:', (iterations - Object.keys(timeMap).length).toLocaleString());
console.log('Clashing microseconds:', (iterations - Object.keys(microMap).length).toLocaleString());
console.log('Sortable:', !uids.slice().sort().find((id, i) => uids[i] !== id))
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way in which I generate unique IDs is by using `Date.now();`

```js
const ID = Date.now();
console.log(ID);
```

The other way is by using a library as `idgp` which can be installed using npm.

The link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/idgp

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    function generateId() {
    return +new Date();
}
```

and then  assign to variable

```
const uniqueId = generateId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that the solution proposed by [@abarber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1921201/abarber) it's a good solution because uses `(new Date()).getTime()` so it has a windows of milliseconds and sum a `tick` in case of collisions in this interval, we could consider to use built-in as
we can clearly see here in action:

Fist we can see here how there can be collisions in the 1/1000 window frame using `(new Date()).getTime()`:

```
console.log( (new Date()).getTime() ); console.log( (new Date()).getTime() )
VM1155:1 1469615396590
VM1155:1 1469615396591
console.log( (new Date()).getTime() ); console.log( (new Date()).getTime() )
VM1156:1 1469615398845
VM1156:1 1469615398846
console.log( (new Date()).getTime() ); console.log( (new Date()).getTime() )
VM1158:1 1469615403045
VM1158:1 1469615403045
```

Second we try the proposed solution that avoid collisions in the 1/1000 window:

```
console.log( window.mwUnique.getUniqueID() ); console.log( window.mwUnique.getUniqueID() ); 
VM1159:1 14696154132130
VM1159:1 14696154132131
```

That said we could consider to use functions like the node `process.nextTick` that is called in the event loop as a single `tick` and it's well explained [here](https://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick).
Of course in the browser there is no `process.nextTick` so we have to figure how how to do that.
[This](https://github.com/wesleytodd/browser-next-tick) implementation will install a `nextTick` function in the browser using the most closer functions to the I/O in the browser that are `setTimeout(fnc,0)`, `setImmediate(fnc)`, `window.requestAnimationFrame`. As suggested [here](http://timnew.me/blog/2014/06/23/process-nexttick-implementation-in-browser/) we could add the `window.postMessage`, but I leave this to the reader since it needs a `addEventListener` as well. I have modified the original module versions to keep it simpler here:

```
getUniqueID = (c => {
 if(typeof(nextTick)=='undefined')
nextTick = (function(window, prefixes, i, p, fnc) {
    while (!fnc && i < prefixes.length) {
        fnc = window[prefixes[i++] + 'equestAnimationFrame'];
    }
    return (fnc && fnc.bind(window)) || window.setImmediate || function(fnc) {window.setTimeout(fnc, 0);};
})(window, 'r webkitR mozR msR oR'.split(' '), 0);
 nextTick(() => {
   return c( (new Date()).getTime() )  
 })
})
```

So we have in the 1/1000 window:

```
getUniqueID(function(c) { console.log(c); });getUniqueID(function(c) { console.log(c); });
undefined
VM1160:1 1469615416965
VM1160:1 1469615416966
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe even better would be to use getTime() or valueOf(), but this way it returns unique plus human understandable number (representing date and time):

```
window.getUniqNr = function() {
  var now = new Date(); 
  if (typeof window.uniqCounter === 'undefined') window.uniqCounter = 0; 
  window.uniqCounter++; 
  var m = now.getMonth(); var d = now.getDay(); 
  var h = now.getHours(); var i = now.getMinutes(); 
  var s = now.getSeconds(); var ms = now.getMilliseconds();
  timestamp = now.getFullYear().toString() 
  + (m <= 9 ? '0' : '') + m.toString()
  +( d <= 9 ? '0' : '') + d.toString() 
  + (h <= 9 ? '0' : '') + h.toString() 
  + (i <= 9 ? '0' : '') + i.toString() 
  + (s <= 9 ? '0' : '') + s.toString() 
  + (ms <= 9 ? '00' : (ms <= 99 ? '0' : '')) + ms.toString() 
  + window.uniqCounter; 

  return timestamp;
};
window.getUniqNr();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let now = new Date();
let timestamp = now.getFullYear().toString();
let month = now.getMonth() + 1;
timestamp += (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month.toString();
timestamp += (now.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + now.getDate().toString();
timestamp += (now.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + now.getHours().toString();
timestamp += (now.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + now.getMinutes().toString();
timestamp += (now.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' : '') + now.getSeconds().toString();
timestamp += (now.getMilliseconds() < 100 ? '0' : '') + now.getMilliseconds().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy and always get unique value :

```
const uniqueValue = (new Date()).getTime() + Math.trunc(365 * Math.random());
**OUTPUT LIKE THIS** : 1556782842762
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way

```
function uniqeId() {
   var ranDom = Math.floor(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random())
   return _.uniqueId(ranDom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUniqueNumber() {

    function shuffle(str) {
        var a = str.split("");
        var n = a.length;
        for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = tmp;
        }
        return a.join("");
    }
    var str = new Date().getTime() + (Math.random()*999 +1000).toFixed() //string
    return Number.parseInt(shuffle(str));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in reference to #Marcelo Lazaroni solution above

```
Date.now() + Math.random()
```

returns a number such as this 1567507511939.4558 (limited to 4 decimals), and will give non-unique numbers (or collisions) every 0.1%.

adding toString() fixes this

`Date.now() + Math.random().toString()`

returns '15675096840820.04510962122198503' (a string), and
 is further so 'slow' that you never get the 'same' millisecond, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Generate Unique Numbers with javascript time V2.0

JavaScript time values: dates as milliseconds since 1970-01-01
100% guaranteed to generate a different number...

```js
let Q = {};
Q.in = document.querySelector('#in');
Q.info = document.querySelector('#butStart');
Q.copy = document.querySelector('#butCopy');
Q.demo = document.querySelector('#demo');

function genUniqueNum() {
    let kol = Q.in.value,
        data, tmp, out = '';
    let i = 0;

    while (i < kol) {
        data = new Date().getTime();
        if (data != tmp) {
            out += `${data}\n`;
            tmp = data;
            i++;
        }
    }
    Q.demo.value += out;
}

function elemTarget(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    return e.target;
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let elem = elemTarget(e);

    if (elem.id === 'butStart') {
        genUniqueNum();
    }
    if (elem.id === 'butCopy' && Q.demo.value) {
        Q.demo.select();
        Q.demo.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
        document.execCommand("copy");
    }
    if (elem.id === 'butClear') {
        Q.demo.value = '';
    }
});
```

```css
#in{
  width: 91px;
}

#butStart,
#butCopy,
#butClear {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 3px 2px 0px 0;
  height: 25px;
}

#butCopy {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#demo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
  <input type="number" id="in" maxlength="1000000" minlength="1" value="5">
  <label> - Amount</label><br>
  <button id="butStart">Start</button><br>
  <textarea id="demo"></textarea><br>
  <button id="butClear">Clear</button><button id="butCopy">Copy</button>
```

[Fork-codepen.io](https://codepen.io/pedro404/pen/dyNorqz)

Answer (score 0):

Using `toString(36)`, slightly slow, here is the faster and unique solution:

```
new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString() +
"-" +
Date.now() +
"-" +
filename.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a unique number:

```
function getUnique(){
    return new Date().getTime().toString() + window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
}
// or 
function getUniqueNumber(){
    const now = new Date();
    return Number([
        now.getFullYear(),
        now.getMonth(),
        now.getDate(),
        now.getHours(),
        now.getMinutes(),
        now.getUTCMilliseconds(),
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0]
    ].join(""));
}
```

Example:

```
getUnique()
"15951973277543340653840"

for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
    console.log( getUnique() );
}
15951974746301197061197
15951974746301600673248
15951974746302690320798
15951974746313778184640
1595197474631922766030

getUniqueNumber()
20206201121832230

for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
    console.log( getUniqueNumber() );
}
2020620112149367
2020620112149336
20206201121493240
20206201121493150
20206201121494200
```

you can change the length using:

```
new Uint8Array(1)[0]
// or
new Uint16Array(1)[0]
// or
new Uint32Array(1)[0]
```

Comment: The question asked for  a unique **number**, not a random string.

Answer (score 0):

This returns unique value even when inside fast loop.

*ofcourse this can be improved much more*

```js
const getUniqueValue = (strength = 2, int=false) => {
    
    const u = () => (Math.random() * 10000).toString().replace('.','');
    
    let r = '';
    
    for (let i=0; i < strength; i++) {
        r += u();
    }
    
    return (int) ? parseInt(r) : r;
}

[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10].map(item => console.log(getUniqueValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my take on this because I wanted a solution where the UID would be:

- Likely unique
- Legible (and can be used in an URL)
- Sortable (by create date)

```
const uid = new Date().toISOString().replaceAll(/[-:TZ]/g, '.') + Math.random().toString().substring(2,7)
// '2022.04.15.03.56.36.197.50167'
```

NOTE: You can tweak the substring second parameter to increase the chances of uniqueness but you will be making the `uid` longer. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function createUniqueId() {
  var date = new Date().getTime();
  var uniqueId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".replace(
    /[xy]/g,
    function (c) {
      var r = (date + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
      date = Math.floor(date / 16);
      return (c == "x" ? r : (r & 0x3) | 0x8).toString(16);
    }
  );
  return uniqueId;
}

console.log(createUniqueId());
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who uses Math.random() isn't truly random as it is a pesudorandom generator.

I just discovered this and it is much much better. I recommend a server NodeJS solution (instead of using browser)

```
// Exists at least Nodejs 16.x.x and above. globalThis.crypto.randomInt is better, more random and support negative range
function randomNumber(min: number, max: number) {
  return globalThis.crypto.randomInt(min, max);
}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-crypto-randomint-method/
The reason it is `globalthis.` is because I'm using this in NodeJS.

Answer (score -4):

just write use autoincrement

```
i=1;
getUnique(){
return i++
}
```

Comment: But if I do `i=1` again somewhere else, this no longer works, right?