# Generating unique IDs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to generate an id in javascript that is guaranteed to be unique. The reason being, I have an app that has multiple tabs. In each of those tabs can be a form that is built dynamically. I want to use labels for the checkboxes in each of those forms, but since it's build dynamically with multiples of the same checkboxes in the dom, I need unique id's for each of them. How can this be accomplished? Or better yet, is there a way to assign the label to a checkbox without needing an id?

Comment: Is the code being built server side (php, etc) or my javascript after page load?

Comment: @BenD it's all done by javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or better yet, is there a way to assign the label to a checkbox without needing an id?

Yes, you can make the `label` element the parent of the `input`:

```
<label>My label: <input type="checkbox"></label>
```

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) (emphasis added):

> The label represents a caption in a user interface. The caption can be
>   associated with a specific form control, known as the label element's
>   labeled control, either using `for` attribute, **or by putting the form
>   control inside the `label` element itself**.

And the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1):

> To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control
>   element must be within the contents of the LABEL element. In this
>   case, the LABEL may only contain one control element.

Comment: really?? i didn't know that! lemme try that real quick

Comment: alright, that worked! thank you soo much. that problem has plagued me for years, but I always just put up with not having the ability to click the label. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: so question: does that mean this won't work in browsers that don't support html-5?

Comment: @LordZardeck - It is also valid according to the HTML 4 spec (I just linked to the HTML5 spec since that's the one I usually adhere to): http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Comment: alright. I mean, i'd just have to put up with it if not, but I'm glad it does work.

Comment: @LordZardeck - If it didn't work you would still have the option of using the `for` attribute. But it will definitely work. I've edited the answer with the relevant quote from the HTML 4.01 spec.

Answer (score 2):

What about using current time as a way of generating unique id?

[Create a unique number with javascript time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012002/create-a-unique-number-with-javascript-time)

Comment: While i prefer to use James' method, this is a good answer also