# Firebase - Firestore - get key with collection.add()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing a problem with the new Firestore from Firebase.

**Situation:** I have a `collection('room')`

I create room with `collection('room').add(room)`

---

**What I'm trying to do:** I need to update a room.

For this, I use: `collection('room').doc(ROOM_ID).update(update)`

So I need to add ROOM_ID in the document in my collection:

```
|room
    ROOM_ID
        id:ROOM_ID,
        someContent: ForTheQuery
```

---

Is there a possible way to achieve that?

An alternative is to create myself a generated ID with:

```
collection('room')
.doc(someId)
.set({
    id: someId,
    someContent: ForTheQuery
});
```

but i want to avoid it.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your proposed solution.  Why don't you want to do it that way?

Comment: Because I'm not certain about the function of generation for ID. I see con and pro for each function so I wont to keep it clean with firebase generation iD.

Comment: So you're asking here how you can add a document with a generated I'd, and also add that id as a property of that document itself?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Yes this is right. And I want to avoid duplicated keys. And I imagine (that can be completely false, correct me if it does not) that Firebase will never have duplicated keys with some checkings. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) to create a reference to a document with a unique id, but the document will not be created yet.  You can then set the contents of that doc by using the unique id that was provided in the document reference:

```
const ref = store.collection('users').doc()
console.log(ref.id)  // prints the unique id
ref.set({id: ref.id})  // sets the contents of the doc using the id
.then(() => {  // fetch the doc again and show its data
    ref.get().then(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data())  // prints {id: "the unique id"}
    })
})
```

Comment: I think it should be noted that setting the id as a field in the ref doc is redundent.  I'm referring to the 'ref.set({id: ref.id})' statement.

Comment: @Tom this can come in handy when you need the unique ID of the document to participate in automatic deserialization.  So, if you have a JavaBean object where the doucment ID should be one of the properties of the object, this will arrange for that property to be automatically set in that object.  This avoids having to write extra code to do that for each deserialization.

Comment: Could this id be used by another request that is running in parallel, for example? How can we assure the integrity of this id and this request that is being executed? Is it thread-safe?

Comment: @LMGagne You can use this id any way you want.  Threadsafety is never an issue, since there is only ever one connection and all operations are pipelined over it.  Not sure what you mean by "integrity".

Comment: Could it be possible for two functions to pull the same id? In this case, the data integrity could also be compromised.

Comment: @LMGagne The chances of two identical IDs being generated for documents in the same collection is astronomically low.  If you're worried about it, you're putting your energy into the wrong worries!

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

**ANGULARFIRE:**

get ID before add database:

```
var idBefore =  afs.createId();
    console.log(idBefore );
```

**ANDROID FIRESTORE:**

```
String idBefore = db.collection("YourCol").document().getId();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is right: they use it in the doc: *https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md*

Answer (score 3):

## Firebase Javascript SDK:

Just use `.id` to get the key, here is an example using `async`/ `await` :

```js
  const KEYID = async() => (await fs.collection("testing").add({ data: 'test'})).id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the ID from the created document by using collection.ref.add(your item without id) and the response (res) will contain the new document reference created with the ID inside it. So get the ID by simply doing res.id.

```
  createOne(options: { item: any, ref: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> }) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if (options.item) {
        // Convert object to pure javascript
        const item = Object.assign({}, options.item);
        console.log('dataService: createOne: set item: ', item);

        options.ref.ref.add(item)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log('dataService: createOne success: res: ', res);
            resolve(res);
          }).catch(err => {
            console.error('dataService: createOne: error: ', err);
            reject(err);
          });
      } else {
        console.log('dataService: createOne: wrong options! options: ', options);
        reject();
      }
    })

    return promise;
  }
```