# Firestore - How to get document id after adding a document to a collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to acquire the document id that was generated after adding a document to a collection?

If I add a document to a collection that represents a "post" in a social media app, I want to get that document id and use it as a field in another document in a different collection.

If I can't get the document Id that was generated after adding a document, should I just compute a random string and supply the id when creating the document instead? That way I can use that same string as the field in my other document?

Quick structure example:

```
POST (collection)
    Document Id - randomly generated by firebase or by me
USER (collection)
    Document Id - randomly generated by firebase
       userPost: String (this will be the document id 
                         in the post collection that I'm trying to get)
```

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46748716/787187). you can generate a key before adding the doc.

Answer (score 111):

Yes it is possible. When you call the `.add` method on a collection, a DocumentReference object is returned. DocumentReference has the `id` field, so you can get the id after the document was created.

```js
// Add a new document with a generated id.
db.collection("cities").add({
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

This example is in JavaScript. Visit the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) for other languages.

Answer (score 41):

If using promises, I'd recommend using fat arrow function as it opens up the possibility for using `this.foo` even in the `.then` function

```js
    db.collection("cities").add({
        name: "Tokyo",
        country: "Japan"
    })
    .then(docRef => {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        console.log("You can now also access this. as expected: ", this.foo)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error("Error adding document: ", error))
```

Using `function(docRef)` means you cannot access `this.foo`, and error will be thrown

```js
    .then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        console.log("You can now NOT access this. as expected: ", this.foo)
    })
```

While fat arrow functions will allow you to access `this.foo` as expected

```js
    .then(docRef => {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        console.log("You can now also access this. as expected: ", this.foo)
    })
```

---

Edit/addition 2020:

A more popular way these days may be to use async/await instead. Notice that you have to add `async` in front of the function declaration:

```js
    async function addCity(newCity) {
      const newCityAdded = await db.collection("cities").add(newCity)
      console.log("the new city:", newCityAdded)
      console.log("it's id:", newCityAdded.id)
    }
```

And if you only want the id it can be grabbed using descructuring. Destructuring allows you to grab any key/value-pair in the response:

```js
    async function addCity(newCity) {
      const { id } = await db.collection("cities").add(newCity)
      console.log("the new city's id:", id)
    }
```

It's also possible to use destructuring to grab the value and rename to whatever you want:

```js
    async function addCity(newCity) {
      const { id: newCityId } = await db.collection("cities").add(newCity)
      console.log("the new city's id:", newCityId)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. I am able to get the document ID. I wanted to then take this id, send the user to a new URL dynamically generated with the ID forming part of the URL and display the data from firebase firestore for that specific document. Any ideas/help welcomed.

Comment: You could use template literals for this: ``window.location.href = `https://mypage.com/${id}` ``. Notice that around the url are not `'` or `"`, but backticks which make it possible to use this method. The alternative would be to create a new string with the id, similar to this: `const newUrl = "https://mypage.com" + id`, then `window.location.href = newUrl`. If you didn't use template literals before, check it out (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), it's great to work with  :)

Answer (score 16):

If you want to use `async/await` instead of `.then()`, you can write it like this:

```
const post = async (doc) => {
    const doc_ref = await db.collection(my_collection).add(doc)
    return doc_ref.id
}
```

If you want to catch any errors in this function, include `.catch()`:

```
    const doc_ref = await db.collection(my_collection).add(doc).catch(err => { ... })
```

or you can have the calling function catch the error.

Answer (score 6):

using v9, you can also get the ID even before creating the document

- Get a new docRef and read its random `id`
- Use the `id` as you want
- For example, insert the `id` in the document data
- Then create the document

```js
const usersRef = collection(db,'users') // collectionRef
const userRef = doc(usersRef) // docRef
const id = userRef.id // a docRef has an id property
const userData = {id, ...} // insert the id among the data
await setDoc(userRef, userData) // create the document
```

Answer (score 4):

For Android, Java, you're suppose to get the Document ID before you `set()` or `add()` something to Firestore. Like so:

```js
    //Fields: 
    CollectionReference toolsCollectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(toolsCollection);
    CustomPOJO_Model toolToPost; 
    
    //In Methods: 
    String newDocID= toolsCollectionRef.document().getId();   //Get Doc ID first. 
    toolToPost.setToolID(newDocID);
    
    //Now use the doc ID:
    toolsCollectionRef.document(newDocID).set(toolToPost.getConvertedTool_KeyValuePair ()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        }
    });
    
    //Re-use same ID in another post: 
    usersCollectionRef.document(mAuth.getUid()).collection(usersToolsCollection).document(toolToPost.getToolID()).set(toolToPost.getConvertedTool_KeyValuePair());
```

Comment: I have been trying to figure out how to get the document id WITHOUT awaiting a Future for years now as I have an app that needs to do everything offline. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

for FB Firestore version 9 (JS/Web) use the following syntax:

```
import { addDoc, doc, Timestamp, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

    //add document to 'posts' collection with auto id
        const newItem = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
                  caption: post.value.caption || "No caption provided",
                  location: post.value.location || "No location provided",
                  imageUrl: imageUrl.value,
                  createdAt: Timestamp.now(), 
            });
                
    //get new document id an update it to the file as id field.
    const fileID = newItem.id
                console.log('added file:', fileID);
                const updateDocId = doc(db, "posts", fileID) ;
                await updateDoc(updateDocId, {
                  id: fileID
              })
```

Comment: Is the error handling still need to be done? I going to look up docs but also wanted to hear others chime in. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned also, we can get the document reference once it added.
After we get the document reference on the behalf of id, we can update the same

Service.ts file

```
async funName(data: Data){
      let docRef = this.firestore.collection('table-name').add(data);
      console.log(docRef)
      try {
        const docAdded = await docRef;
        console.log(docAdded.id);
        this.firestore.doc('table-name/' + docAdded.id).update({ id: docAdded.id });
        return docRef;
      }
      catch (err) {
        return err;
      }
    }
```

component.ts file

```
async addData(){
    try{
      let res =  await this.dataServ.funName(this.form.value);
      this.snackbar.open('success', 'Success');
    }catch(ex){
      this.disabled = false;
      this.snackbar.open('err', 'Error')
      console.log(ex, 'exception');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9) in firebase v9 i think you'd want to use `addDoc()` method like so:

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document with a generated id.
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "cities"), {
  name: "Tokyo",
  country: "Japan"
});
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
```

There is also `setDoc()` method which allows you to set your own id for the document

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document in collection "cities"
await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "YOUR_CUSTOM_ID"), {
  name: "Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this one was voted out. This is what I needed I was looking for adding the doc().set() instead of doc().add().
I will be using uuid as the document to search for my users inside collection.

```
firebase.firestore().collection("cities").doc().set({ name: Tokyo,
country: Japan })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Future<void> addAllGame(
  {required String? user,
  required String gameName,
  required int fee,
  required String date,
  required List options}) async {
DocumentReference documentRef = await allGame.add({
  "userName": user,
  "gameName": gameName,
  "options": options,
  'fee': fee,
  'date': date
});
print("show doc id");
print(documentRef.id);
```

}

Answer (score -3):

Here's what I do, as mentioned in your question. Not sure if it is best practice, but it works for easy access.

When creating the document in the first place

```
firebase.firestore().collection("cities").doc().set({ name: Tokyo,
country: Japan })
```

you can set the id of the doc and put that exact id in it as a property:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("cities").doc('id-generated-from-somewhere')
.set({ id: 'id-generated-from-somewhere', name: Tokyo, country: Japan })
```

Comment: This is just too much for you to handle. You might end up generating an ID that already exists and that would corrupt your data.