# Add a field property to a document in firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I call a method every time button add is clicked. In this method I create a new document for my collection which contains a title and an array of strings. The creation of this document get done in my method by calling a method from my saved service. I want to add a last String value field to my document when complete button is clicked. How can I get a snapshot of the current saved id in order to add a new element?
I am using Angular and firestore

These buttons are located in component.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onComplete()">Complete</button>
```

OnSave and onComplete are located in component.ts

```
onSave() {

    const btn = document.getElementById("addtopic");
    this.modalService.hide(1);

    // Get starting date
    this.startTopicTimestamp=  firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
    console.log(`Starting time : ${this.startTopicTimestamp}`);

    btn.innerHTML = "End topic";
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger');

    // New document creation
    this.savedService.savedDoc(this.topicTitle, this.myTags, this.startTopicTimestamp);
}


onComplete(){

    // Here we should get a snapshot of the current saved id
    // To make this function work
    this.savedService.addElement(this.saved.id)

}
```

This method is part of savedService

```
public savedDoc(title: string, tags: string[], date: Date): void {

    const savedFields = {
      title: title,
      startTime: date,
      tags: tags
    }

   this.db.collection('saved').add(savedFields);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `savedService` method?

Comment: @zavtra The addElement method is a method I want to create, since I can receive the current saved.id

Comment: @ManWeb We need to see how do you write to Firestore. This is why zavtra asks you to share the code of `savedService.createSavedDoc()`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec  I have updated my post and code.

Answer (score 1):

According to this ([Firestore - How to get document id after adding a document to a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740430/firestore-how-to-get-document-id-after-adding-a-document-to-a-collection)), you can just do this:

```
public savedDoc(title: string, tags: string[], date: Date): void {

    const savedFields = {
      title: title,
      startTime: date,
      tags: tags
    }

   return this.db.collection('saved').add(savedFields).then(function(docRef) {
    return docRef.id;

});
}
```

Because `add` returns a `DocumentReference`

Comment: Since the OP "wants to add a last String value field to my document when complete button is clicked" you could directly return the `DocumentReference` to use it later on, e.g. by calling the `update()` method.

Comment: This service call of saveDoc will return an id value as docRef in this case . What value do I  need to assign the return docRef.id so I can use it later? @RenaudTarnec

Comment: What I mean is that it could do `return docRef;` instead of `return docRef.id;` and then you would directly do `docRef.update()` instead of re-building the `DocumentReference` from the id. This is just a minor remark however.

Comment: Okay now I got it. I wanted to ask that in this answer we return docRef.id. So if I want to save it to a global var since we return its value through this method, what kind of var should be declared in component to get this id? Should it be a string? @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Yes, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#id

Comment: @zavtra Return give me back a ZoneAwarePromise which contains the id. How can I get the id directly?

Comment: Just return the id and then set a variable by `await`ing the call

Comment: const cardId  = this.savedService.savedDoc(this.topicTitle, this.myTags, this.startTopicTimestamp); How do I set it to a await response?