# How to get back document after set, firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get back the documument ID after I set a new one?

I have a few attempts but here is my latest:

```
handleCreateCard = async (name, token) => {
    try {
        const new_card = await firestore()
          .collection('Cards')
          .doc()
          .set({
            user_id: user.uid,
            name: name,
            token: token,
          })
          .then(function(docRef) {
              console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
          })
          .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate("CardDetail", {cardId: 2}));

//              console.log("ATTEMPT !", handleCreateCard);
//              console.log("ATTEMPT 2", new_card);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.toString(error));
        }
    }
```

The `docRef` line gets me the error:

Error:  `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'docRef.id')`

Logging handleCreateCard
Error:  `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: handleCreateCard`

Then the `new_card`:  "THIS IS HERE undefined"

Tried doing:

```
.then(docRef => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", this.id); // also tried docRef.id
})
```

I get `Document written with ID: undefined`
with docRef.id: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'docRef.id')`

The document is being created as well so not sure why it's not coming back

I've tried a handful of ways to do this and then also tried everything in here which some is above: [Firestore - How to get document id after adding a document to a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740430/firestore-how-to-get-document-id-after-adding-a-document-to-a-collection)

Not sure why it's not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the API documentation, [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) with no parameters returns a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) immediately which already contains the ID.

```js
const docRef = await firestore()
    .collection('Cards')
    .doc()
const id = docRef.id
docRef
    .set(...)
    .then(/* use the id here if you want */)
```

Comment: Hm that works thanks.  So i guess I "create" it first, get the ID, then set? Is that what is happening?

Comment: Yes, the random ID is generated on the client before the document is actually created.