# Get document id after adding a document in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

aftwe carefully reating [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740430/firestore-how-to-get-document-id-after-adding-a-document-to-a-collection). I still cant get the document auto genereated ID. There is no "then" option.
My code:

```
var mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
mFirestore.firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().build()

val rls: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
rls["title"] = "some data"

var pop = mFirestore.collection("Users").document("mic").collection("Rls")
pop.add(rls)
```

How to get an ID after creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var docID = mFirestore.collection("Users").document("mic").collection("Rls").document()
```

The above will generate a random document id, then when adding data you can do:

```
var pop = mFirestore.collection("Users").document("mic").collection("Rls").document(docID.id)
pop.set(rls)
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), in order to let firestore autogenerate an id, you use the 'add' function like this:

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
val data = hashMapOf(
        "name" to "Tokyo",
        "country" to "Japan"
)

db.collection("cities")
    .add(data)
    .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: ${documentReference.id}")
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e)
    }
```

You can then retrieve the id within the 'addOnSuccessListener' from 'documentReference'.id.

Edit:
Make sure to initialize your firestore db like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart):

```
// Access a Cloud Firestore instance from your Activity
val db = Firebase.firestore
```