# How can I get the id of a inserted document firebase-admin

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am handling some documents with firebase realtime database. I need to delete a document that I don't have the access to read it client side via SDK. In order to do that I need to know what is the id, so I should store it in my db (mongo) and when I need to delete a document on firebase I just get it from my DB and the I delete it.

I took a look [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740430/firestore-how-to-get-document-id-after-adding-a-document-to-a-collection) but it doesn't work for me.

I insert documents into my firebase DB with this method (server side using `firebase-admin`)

```
const writeNotification = (uid: string, notification: INotification) => {
  const db = admin.database();
  const notsRef = db.ref(`notifications/${uid}`);
  notsRef.push({
    ..._.omit(notification, 'to'),
  });
};
```

If I do `notsRef.id` I get `undefined`.

How can I get the ID of my document that I have just inserted?

p.s. my documents are organized like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are looking at is about [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore) and not [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/database) that you are using. The [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference) has a [`key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#key) property and not `id`:

```
console.log('New Key', notsRef.key) 

// to get child node's key
const childNotesRef = notsRef.push({
    ..._.omit(notification, 'to'),
  });

console.log(childNotesRef.key)
```

Comment: Hi Dharma! That's right, but in that way I get the "father's" key. In the screenshot above I would get `FhN6Ntw8gyPLwJYVzcHy0E8Wq5z2`. What if I want to get `-MzGhZ2psGLivIfTWt6J` key? which is the actual thing i need to delete

Comment: Hey @Loudrous, the push returns a Reference too so you can get the ID from there. You can also get the ID after pushing the data like: `push(..).then(ref => console.log(ref.key))

Comment: you are right! gg