# .add() in firebase cloud firestore nested objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The firebase documentation says this about updating in nested objects: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

My structure

```
let ref = db.collections('projects').doc('blabla')
ref.set({
    objOfObjects: {}
})
```

I would like to add an object(value) with a randomly generated key to objOfObjects, much like the regular add function. I can't tie the key to any of the values of the object. Is there a way to add to objOfObjects or do I have to restructure my data?

Comment: post the firebase structure that you wants to update or any screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function add a field with a randomly generated name to a document. But you can generate the random name yourself and add it. You can even use `collection.add()` to generate the random name, since (as [Doug says here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747775/firebase-firestore-get-key-with-collection-add)) that doesn't actually create a document yet.

```
var newId = store.collection('projects').doc().id;

let ref = db.collections('projects').doc('blabla');
var updates = {};
updates[id] = { ... }
ref.update(updates)
```

The tricks used here:

- Get a new unique id, as explained before.
- Use `[]` notation to use the value of that id as the property *name*.
- Call `update()` to update a document, instead of replacing it.