# Firebase Firestore: get generated ID of document (Python)

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I can create a new document (with auto generated ID), and store a reference to it like this:

```
my_data = {"key": "value"}
doc_ref = db.collection(u'campaigns').add(my_data)
```

I can access the data itself like:

```
print (doc_ref[0]) # prints {"key": "value"}
```

But when I try to access the doc_ref ID, I am unable to:

```
# All of these throw attribute errors
doc_ref.get()
doc_ref.data()
doc_ref.id
```

[There are other posts which suggest how to do this in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747775/firebase-firestore-get-key-with-collection-add?rq=1), but none which work for the Python SDK!

**How can I access the generated ID of a document I created?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The documentation is unclear, but I finally got it to work:

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'campaigns').document()
doc_ref.set(my_data)
print(doc_ref.id)
```

Comment: So simple, and yet so hard to find. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**To get ID after save on Python:**

This will return for instance some id like **wlJQKyVDsIIpX0x3NBmt**

```
doc_ref = db.collection('promotions').add(data)
return doc_ref[1].id
```

Answer (score 3):

Documentation is very limited on this, but I managed to figure it out through trial and error.

If you want to use `add` method as the question indicates, instead of a document reference together with a `set` method, try:

```
my_data = {"key": "value"}
response = db.collection(u'campaigns').add(my_data)
id = response[1].id
data = response[1].get().to_dict()
```

Firestore response when using `add` method contains a tuple:

1. `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` object - contains the time the document was created
2. Firestore document reference that contains `id` and a document snapshot, from which you can extract the document data by chaining `get()` and `to_dict()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id from document even before set method is called

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'campaigns').document()
id = doc_ref.id
```

Then do to save:

```
doc_ref(my_data)
```