# Subcollection id

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want users to have projects and I want projects to have an `id` that was made by my function. Then to make a condition and display one project.

This error is generated, if I leave `auto id` creation, then everything is fine

```js
 try {
 my function
     let id = new Date().valueOf();

    const res = await firestore
      .collection("Projects")
      .doc(userId).collection("project")
      .get();

   

    if (!res.data()) {
      firestore
        .collection("Projects")
        .doc(userId)
        .collection("project").doc(id)//my func id
        .add({
        
        data
        });
    } else {
      firestore
        .collection("Projects")
        .doc(userId)
        .collection("project").doc(id)//my func id
        .update({
        ...res.data().project, data
        });
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create it with a custom ID you need to use `.set()`, instead of `.add()`.  Basically, I think this way you will overwrite the custom assigned id. It should be something like this :

```
firestore
    .collection("Projects")
    .doc(userId)
    .collection("project").doc("YOUR_CUSTOM_ID")
    .set({

    data
    });
```

You can find more info about adding data in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

Comment: Leave auto_id creation on, an just use set afterwards

Comment: i want to map() all users project.How will I contact auto generated id?

Comment: As it is stated in the official documentation : "To create or overwrite a single document, use the set() method:" . You do not need that "else" . If you use "set" in case it exists it overwrites and in case it does not, it creates it. Read more about it in the documentation. You do not need the if/else structure. Just use "set".  -- "f the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document"

Comment: I want a unique id and not a string, this id will be in my address bar

Comment: If you would like to create a custom id name for your doc you can do as @AndreiTigau suggested. Otherwise, if you would like to create a unique id, you can use `.doc()`. As the **[documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc)** points out, if no path is specified inside `.doc()`, an automatically-generated unique ID will be used for the returned DocumentReference. This **[SO case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747775/firebase-firestore-get-key-with-collection-add?noredirect=1&lq=1)** shows you an example.