# Does Firestore incur charges for generating document ID?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a Flutter application, I'm using the following code frequently to generate a document ID before writing the document to Firestore *(to include the document ID inside the document)*:

```
docID = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc().id
```

Will this incur a read charge every time I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wont incur a read charge. You will only be charged for the write, because you are not actually reading anything off Firestore, the ID is generated client-side.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does Firestore ensure that the generated ID is unique to that collection if it's generated in the client-side?

Comment: you can actually read the source code of how they do that, the question is asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618719/firestore-are-ids-unique-in-the-collection-or-globally .tl;dr : it's just based on math.random(), so it's not guaranteed to be unique

Comment: Such IDs are statistically guaranteed to be unique, which is a fancy way of saying that it's so random that the chances of two calls generating the same ID are infinitely small.