# Will I possibly loose any decimal digits (precision) when multiplying Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER by Math.random()?

Tags: javascript, math, random, numbers

Will I possibly loose any decimal digits (precision) when multiplying [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) by [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) in JavaScript?

I presume I won't but it'd be nice to have a credible explanation as to why

**Edited**, In layman terms, we're dealing with two [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) double-precision floating-point numbers, one is the maximal integer (for double-precision), the other one is fractional with quite a few digits after a decimal point. What if (say) I first converted them to [quadruple-precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format), then multiplied, and then converted the product back to double-precision, would the result be any different?

```js
const max = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
const random = Math.random();
console.log(`\
MAX_SAFE_INTEGER: ${max}, \
random: ${random}, \
product: ${max * random}`);
```

For more elaborate examples, I use it to generate [`BigInt` random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39032011/1768303).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation should be safe - in theory, all numbers between 0 and MAX_SAFE_INTEGER should have a possibility of appearing, if the engine implementing `Math.random` uses a completely unbiased algorithm.

But an absolutely unbiased algorithm is not guaranteed by the specification - the numbers chosen are meant to be *psuedo* random, not *truly, completely* random. <sup>(does such a thing even exist? it's debatable...)</sup> Modern versions V8 and some other implementations [use an algorithm](https://v8.dev/blog/math-random) with a period on the order of 2 ** 128, larger than MAX_SAFE_INTEGER (2 ** 53 - 1) - but it'd be completely plausible for other implementations (especially older ones) to have a much smaller period, resulting in certain integers within the range being picked much more often than others.

If this is important for your script (which is pretty unlikely in most situations, I'd think), you *might* consider using a [higher-quality random generatior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) than `Math.random` - but it's almost certainly not worth worrying about.

Comment: I'd be ok with reappearing numbers, but, in simple words, I was rather concerned that I multiple one big IEEE-754-represented integer number by another very small fractional one. So as a result, I thought I might be loosing some precision. Are you saying this is not the case? I admit I need to read up on [IEEE-754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), it's been a while since my Uni days :)

Comment: All numbers will have 52 bits of precision, whether huge or small, decimal or not, and that precision will carry over when the numbers are operated on (and *then* less significant digits are discarded), so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

> What if (say) I first converted them to quadruple-precision format, then multiplied, and then converted the product back to double-precision, would the result be any different?

It could be in cases where the rounding behaves differently between multiplying two doubles vs converting quadruple to double, but the main problem remains the same. The spacing between representable doubles in the range from 2<sup>n</sup> to 2<sup>n+1</sup> is 2<sup>n−52</sup>. So between 2<sup>52</sup> and 2<sup>53</sup> only whole numbers can be represented, between 2<sup>51</sup> and 2<sup>52</sup> only every 0.5 can be represented, etc.

If you want more precision you could try [decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/#Dmul). The library is included on that documentation page so you can try these out in your console.

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER*.9
8106479329266892
new Decimal(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).mul(new Decimal(0.9)).toString()
"8106479329266891.9"
```

Comment: Thanks and hey, nice to hear from you @rjschnorenberg! And of course, you're right :) I've verified that with C#, where `double` is represented by the same `binary64` format: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m6HKuL

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are correct, but I couldn't help running this little experiment in C#, where `double` is the same thing as `Number` in JavaScript ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9LPxi1)):

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    const double MAX_SAFE_INT = 9007199254740991;
    Decimal maxD = Convert.ToDecimal(MAX_SAFE_INT.ToString());
    var rng = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
    { 
        double random = rng.NextDouble();
        double product = MAX_SAFE_INT * random;
      
        // converting via string to workaround the "15 significant digits" limitation for Decimal(Double)
        Decimal randomD = Decimal.Parse(String.Format("{0:F18}", random));
        
        Decimal productD = maxD * randomD;
        double converted = Convert.ToDouble(productD);
        if (Math.Floor(converted) != Math.Floor(product)) 
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"{maxD}, {randomD, 22}, products: decimal {productD, 32}, converted {converted, 20}, original {product, 20}");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I'm concerned, I'm still getting the desired distribution of the random numbers within the `0 - 9007199254740991` range.

Here is a [JavaScript playground code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68061302/1768303) to check for possible recurrences.